# Use leaflet.canvaslayer.field.js in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've tried to work with the [leaflet.canvaslayer.field.js](https://github.com/IHCantabria/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field) plugin in standard html to display some GeoTiff and now I would like some help to understand how i can port the code into a react component.

My javascript code is:

```js
d3.request('http://localhost:4000/map_tif/?band=223').responseType('arraybuffer').get(
 function(error, tiffData) {
   console.log(tiffData.response);
   let ndvi = L.ScalarField.fromGeoTIFF(tiffData.response);
   ndvi.isContinuous = false
   ndvi.longitudeNeedsToBeWrapped = false
   console.log(ndvi)
   let layer = L.canvasLayer.scalarField(ndvi, {
   color: chroma.scale('Spectral').domain(ndvi.range.reverse()),
   opacity: 1,
   inFilter: (v) => v !== 0
   }).addTo(map);

   layer.on('click', function(e) {
   if (e.value !== null) {
   let v = e.value.toFixed(2);
   let html = (`<span class = "popupText"> Temperature ${v} °C</span>`);
   let popup = L.popup()
   .setLatLng(e.latlng)
   .setContent(html)
   .openOn(map);
   }
   });
   map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would have to install the following dependencies via npm:

- chroma.js
- @turf/insid
- geotiff.js
- d3js
  which are required by the plugin and then import them into your component.

However, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/IHCantabria/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/issues/33) this plugin must be included via a  tag and cannot be easily imported into a modern bundled JS application via standard import/require syntax)

Import the first 3 dependencies via a script tag on index.html as they are required for the plugin script.
index.html:

```
...
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://npmcdn.com/geotiff@0.3.6/dist/geotiff.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/1.3.0/chroma.min.js"></script>
...
```

Script tag does not work either for some reason in a React project so you can load the script asynchronously and access it on load.

```
const mapRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;

    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://ihcantabria.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/dist/leaflet.canvaslayer.field.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => loaded(map);

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);

  const loaded = map => {
    var tiff =
      "https://ihcantabria.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/data/tz850.tiff";
    fetch(tiff)
      .then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
      .then(function(buffer) {
        var s = L.ScalarField.fromGeoTIFF(buffer);
        let layer = L.canvasLayer.scalarField(s).addTo(map);
        layer.on("click", function(e) {
          if (e.value !== null) {
            L.popup()
              .setLatLng(e.latlng)
              .setContent(`${e.value}`)
              .openOn(map);
          }
        });

        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
      });
  };
```

You can see a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-leafletcanvaslayerfieldjs-in-react-10rw2) with [this](https://codepen.io/VictorVelarde/pen/ZKJWMb/) example rewritten in React from the official page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it later and come back to you

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I already have some other layers in a Map.js and would like to have this Geotiff as an Overlay. Do you have any Idea in how should i do? I'm sorry but i'm really new of this world

Comment: This is another question my friend. You should post it in a different thread. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: you are right! I'll open another question then :) and yes it helped me a lot